# Exact details of Embedding layer in Keras

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, embedding

I want to understand the Embedding layer in Keras. Can anyone help? I cannot find any good reference.

1. Which algorithm is working? I mean based on which paper or method? I want details to
   implement it myself.
2. how the training data for embedding is created? It is 2 words 2 words or more neighbors...
3. How the model updates the weights? is it first embedding then model, or both update
   together?
4. How the parameters is calculated? For example i have this simple model:

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Embedding(input_dim=15, output_dim=8, input_length=4))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.summary()

and this is the summary:

Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param 

=================================================================
embedding (Embedding)        (None, 4, 8)              120       
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 32)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 1)                 33
```

how the 120 is calculated?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to the site. Could you clarify whether you want reference to papers or explanation for the above code?

Comment: In terms of the number 120, that is the number of weights that need to be stored for the embedding layer specified. If the embedding layer has an input dimension of 15 (15 possible input categories or words) and an output dimension of 8 (each category represented by an 8-dimensional array), then the total number of weights or parameters stored by the embedding layer is 15x8=120.

Comment: @user79161 pls notice that asking for references is explicitly off-topic in SO

Answer (score 0):

In terms of the number of parameters (120), that is the number of weights that need to be stored for the embedding layer specified. If the embedding layer has an input dimension of 15 (15 possible input categories or words) and an output dimension of 8 (each category represented by an 8-dimensional array), then the total number of weights or parameters stored by the embedding layer is 15x8=120.

The embedding weights themselves can either be provided prior to training (using pretrained weights: https://keras.io/examples/nlp/pretrained_word_embeddings/) or the weights can be learned during the model training process. In the latter case the method of learning is the same as the rest of the network, presumably some form of gradient descent in an effort to minimize loss against the provided target. You can choose to train or freeze the weights using the ‘trainable’ keyword argument when initializing the embedding layer.

Comment: Thank you, but i want to know what is exactly "presumably some form of gradient descent in an effort to minimize loss against the provided target" means. I need details to implement it myself from scratch. So what is the algorithm, paper, ...

Comment: I think most neural networks are trained with gradient descent. The weights of the network are updated according to the derivative of loss function evaluated on the true target and the predicted target. My understanding of deep learning libraries is that they abstract this process away so you don't have to manage the gradient descent computations themselves or the complex backpropagation steps required to update all the weights.